# Failed to read key from store Invalid keystore format codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am failing create a build online for release on Playstore. This is the build error message that i am facing.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.

  > Failed to read key essap from store "/tmp/build8775516520051228608xxx/EssentialService/keyStore": Invalid keystore format
- Try:
  Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.

Answer (score 0):

I used the codenameone settings application to generate. Its found right click project -> codename one -> Settings  [image]